# Phrasal verbs and terminal prepositions

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

> This is the house where I grew up.

If we accept the (debatable) rule that a sentence should not end in a preposition, are phrasal verbs an exception?  After all there is no other place in the above sentence where "up" might fit, for example:

> This is the house where up I grew

Or, must we eschew the phrasal verb in favor of a synonym,

> This is the house where I **was raised**
>
> This is **my childhood home**
>
> This is the house where I **spent my childhood**

etc.

(Note: I am aware of [this similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131992/phrasal-verb-or-preposition-at-the-end-of-a-sentence), but since it is not actually about a phrasal verb, it does not answer my question.  I'm also aware of the famously misattributed Churchill quote, but feel free to repeat it.)

Comment: I believe that educated people who think the "rule" you mention has any validity (I have the impression that there are very few of these) consider "up" in sentences like this to be an *adverb,* not a *preposition*: hence, the proscription against ending a sentence in a preposition would be irrelevant. (It's easy to find dictionary entries that call "up" an adverb.) The idea that prepositions can be "intransitive", so to speak, and not have any noun phrase as a complement is somewhat controversial.

Comment: Here are some related posts about the categorization of words as prepositions vs. adverbs: *[What part of speech would “away” be?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/352443), [Is “now” a “preposition”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/291007), [Is there any real difference between “to” as a preposition and “to” as an adverb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117290)*

Comment: There's no rule to be an exception to! Whether part of a verbal idiom or some other construction, preposition stranding is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: In any case, do not eschew the phrasal verb, and put its second part wherever it sounds best.

Comment: Some transitive MWVs are inseparable (I came across this great book on origami.) Some are optionally separable (I turned on the light / I turned the light on). And some are obligatorily separable (Their exquisite finish sets these model cars apart.)  But even the inseparable cases/usages can be used with particles at the end of a sentence (Look at this great book I came across.) As can particles in intransitive MWVs (Let's get out of here before Kong comes to!) But the 'rule' is best considered incorrect, not debatable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on an assumption as near to false as makes no difference. Also, 'follow through with' is certainly a transitive MWV, just like unitary 'continue with' and 'stick with'. {[McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/follow+through): << follow through (with something) ...
to complete an activity, doing what was promised. I wish you would [follow through with] / [complete] the project we talked about. >>}

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  Not an *assumption*, a *presumption*; meaning "for the sake of argument, take it as true that ..."  Since the "rule" is well known and commonly followed, it's not an outlandish supposition. But if this still breaks the rules, that's fine.

Comment: The assumption {_assume_: to accept something to be true without question or proof [CED](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/assume)} is that 'sentences may not end in a preposition'; this assumption is as near to false (ie the statement is incorrect) as makes no difference. You've based your question on _this_ false assumption. You're not into the realm of non-Euclidean geometry, but how English is actually used. Sentences that end in a preposition are not (necessarily) unacceptable. There has been a lot of discussion on this; Pullum has said the 'rule' is not a rule.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that when it comes to phrasal verbs, the preposition is not a true preposition, but rather a particle that is part of the phrasal verb compound. Therefore even when ending with what looks like a preposition, it has no prepositional function and you have ended the sentence with a verb.

If you say "that boy just threw up," you are not saying that he threw something into the air; you are not saying he threw something at all. You are saying that the boy performed an act of regurgitation. Full stop. Up is not a preposition in this sentence, it just looks like one.

Comment: However, "count on" is a phrasal verb that takes an object.  And sometimes it's a phrasal verb, and sometimes not.  You can count on your fingers, or you can count on someone to do something for you.

Comment: A particle is a small word, usually a preposition, that can freely come between a verb and its direct object, as in "She took the suitcase **down**" ~ "She took **down** the suitcase. But "up" is not a particle in "That boy just threw up", since there is no object. In any case, it's not "threw up" that is a verb; it's just the lexeme "threw"; this is the word that takes the verbal inflections. So we have "Whenever he drinks, he throws up, but not *"Whenever he drinks he throw ups".

Comment: @BillJ does that apply to all phrasal verbs?  It sounds like it only works with the *intransitive* ones, but what about the transitive ones, e.g. "I'll **look after** him"?

Comment: @Xanne well in the one case it is a phrasal verb, and in the other a verb plus preposition.

Comment: @BillJ throw up is a distinct verb from throw, as it has distinct lexical meaning which is lost in the absence of the particle up. Just like throw down. Just because a particle can come between a verb and it's object does not mean that they cannot occur on intransitive verbs. As far as psycholinguistic perception, the two parts of a phrasal verb are as integral as the two parts of a compound noun. If you take the bath out of bird bath, you have a completely different object.

Comment: @Andrew A particle can only occur with a transitive verb since by definition particles are the only complements that can come between the verb and its direct object. In your example "I'll look after him", "him" is object of the prep "after", not of the verb "look".

Comment: A particle by definition is (mainly) a preposition that can freely come between a verb and it direct object, so it can hardly occur with an intransitive verb.

Comment: In the case of the inappropriately named "phrasal verbs", the crucial point is that the two parts do not form a constituent at word level. In for example "They fell out", "fell out" is not a constituent at word level: it’s a VP. Verb is a word category, like noun, adjective, etc., and it’s "fell" that is a verb: this is the word that takes verbal inflections. So we can have "They had fallen out" but not *"They had fall outed".

Answer (score 1):

A phrasal verb is a combination of a verb and an adverb particle. There is no preposition in a phrasal verb. The most common adverb particles used to form phrasal verbs are **around, at, away, down, in, off, on, out, over, round, up**.

> This is the house where I grew up.

In the above sentence, **grew up** is a phrasal verb and the word **up** here is an adverb particle. If you move the particle before the verb, it will no longer be a phrasal verb and it will not convey the same meaning.

A phrasal verb can be transitive or intransitive. When the phrasal verb is transitive, the adverb particle may come before or after the object if the object is not a personal pronoun (me, you, him, us, etc.).

Prepositional verbs which look similar to phrasal verbs are another type of multi-word verb. Prepositional verbs have two parts: a verb and a preposition which cannot be separated from each other. Example: **break into** (a house), **get over** (an illness) etc.

Prepositional verbs always have an object, which comes immediately after the preposition.

Source: [Cambridge English Grammar: Phrasal verbs and multi-word verbs](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/british-grammar/phrasal-verbs-and-multi-word-verbs)

Answer (score 0):

> If we accept the (debatable) rule that a sentence should not end in a preposition, are phrasal verbs an exception?

Yes.  The second (and third) words of a phrasal verbs work more like adverbs than prepositions.